# Online version of bellman-ford algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

Suppose I have a graph on which I've run the Bellman-Ford algorithm. Now I change the weight of subset of edges. Is there an efficient way to re-run the algorithm without having to completely start over? That is, can I update the shortest path in an "online" manner, if I'm only changing a subset of weight edges each time?

Comment: The phrase for algorithms for updating when a small number of edges have changed is "dynamic" algorithms.  Try a literature search to see if you can find any dynamic algorithms for network flow.